# Cakephp3 cache duration not expiring

Tags: caching, cakephp-3.0, cache-expiration

Hello everyone I work with cakephp3 I have implemented the cache from [doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-engines) but the duration to expire the cache does not apply.
I tried to use minutes and hours in the duration but it doesn't work
thanks for your help.

Here is my cache configuration

```
'Cache' => [
    'access_token' => [
    'className' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+2 minutes',
    'path' => CACHE
   ]
],
```

and here I created my cache with my configuration:

```
Cache::write("access_token\_$key", $response, 'access_token');
```

The cache does not expire after 2 minutes, I also tried to use +1 hours instead of +2 minutes but still it does not work

Comment: Does it expire faster than that, or does it not expire even though you think it should?

Comment: When I put 2 minutes as duration it almost expires in 9 min

Comment: That's an extremely weird number. You are referencing it regularly during those 9 minutes and it keeps giving the old version for that whole time?

Comment: Yes and when I put +1 hours it does not expire in 9 minutes I wait 1 hour but it does not expire that's an weird

Comment: Ah I fixed my prob by restaring my laptop, it's a caching problem